# Digit Frequency In A String

Tags: java, string

I am supposed to do this :

> For an input number print frequency of each number in the order of its occurrence.For eg :
>   Input:56464
>   Output:
>   Number-Frequency
>   5 -1
>   6 -2
>   4 -2

I cannot use any other libraries except java.lang and Scanner to input
So I tried this :

```
package practice2;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class DigitFrequency2
{

    private static Scanner sc;

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter an integer number");
        String sb = sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Number\tFrequency");

        int i,x,c = 0;

        for(i=0;i<sb.length();i++)
        {
            c = 0;
            for(x = i+1;x<sb.length();x++)
            {
                if(sb.charAt(i) == sb.charAt(x) && sb.charAt(i) != '*' && sb.charAt(x) != '*')
                {
                    c++;
                    sb.replace(sb.charAt(x),'*');
                }
            }

            if(c>0)
            {
                System.out.println(sb.charAt(i)+"     \t"+c);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

---

```
Number  Frequency
6       1
4       1
```

Where am I going wrong please help.

Comment: Well, `sb.replace()` doesn't do anything in your code: String is immutable.  Possibly you meant to assign the String to a StringBuilder?

Comment: I cannot use StringBuilder :(

Comment: I have done it with stringbuilder here http://pastebin.com/vvDsvHYm

Comment: "I cannot use StringBuilder" why? It is part of `java.lang` package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is that as mentioned, `String` is immutable, so `String.replace()` just returns a new string and it does not (cannot) modify the original. Either you should use `StringBuilder`, or store the returned value (e.g. `sb = sb.replace(sb.charAt(x),'*');`).

Going further, since you initialize `c` with `0`, it will stay `0` if there is no other occurrence of the character in question (`sb.charAt(i)`), so your algorithm won't detect and print digits that occur only once (because later you only print if `c > 0`).

Counting occurrences (frequency) of characters or digits in a string is a simple operation, it does not require to create new strings and it can be done by looping over the characters only once.

Here is a more efficient solution (one of the fastest). Since digits are in the range `'0'..'9'`, you can create an array in which you count the occurrences, and by looping over the characters only once. No need to replace anything.  Order of occurrence is "remembered" in another `order` char array.

```
char[] order = new char[10];
int[] counts = new int[10];
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
    if (counts[sb.charAt(i) - '0']++ == 0)
        order[j++] = sb.charAt(i); // First occurrence of the digit
```

And print in order, until the `order` array is filled:

```
System.out.println("Number\tFrequency");
for (int i = 0; order[i] != 0; i++)
    System.out.println(order[i] + "\t" + counts[order[i] - '0']);
```

Example output:

```
Enter an integer number
56464
Number  Frequency
5       1
6       2
4       2
```

For completeness here's the complete `main()` method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter an integer number");
    String sb = new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();

    char[] order = new char[10];
    int[] counts = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sb.length(); i++)
        if (counts[sb.charAt(i) - '0']++ == 0)
            order[j++] = sb.charAt(i); // First occurrence of the digit

    System.out.println("Number\tFrequency");
    for (int i = 0; order[i] != 0; i++)
        System.out.println(order[i] + "\t" + counts[order[i] - '0']);
}
```

**Note:**

If you would want to make your code safe against invalid inputs (that may contain non-digits), you could use `Character.isDigit()`. Here is only the `for` loop which is safe against any input:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < sb.length(); i++) {
    char ch = sb.charAt(i);
    if (Character.isDigit(ch)) {
        if (counts[ch - '0']++ == 0)
            order[j++] = ch; // First occurrence of ch
    }
}
```

Comment: It has to be in order of occurrence

Comment: @RayyanMerchant Sorry, I missed that in your question. See edited answer which now tracks and prints in occurrence order.

Comment: Can any of the downvoters comment why the downvotes?

Answer (score 3):

Simple way is this. Won't bother commenting as it is clear whats going on.

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
while (true) {
    System.out.print("Input String: ");
    String line = in.nextLine();

    while (!line.isEmpty()) {
        char c = line.charAt(0);
        int length = line.length();
        line = line.replace(String.valueOf(c), "");
        System.out.println(c + " " + (length - line.length()));
    }
}
```

Comment: Concise and resourceful solution. This won't sort the output by frequency though.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yeah well he didn't want it in frequency. "order of its occurrence" This will work for everything though. He can always retrofit it to his needs such as "only integers" and whatnot.

Comment: Lolz. Now I understand why nobody bothered... You are absolutely right! 'Occurrence' obviously isn't the same thing as 'number of occurrences'. +1 from me

Answer (score 1):

There are few problems with `sb.replace(sb.charAt(x),'*');`:

1. `replace` replaces all characters, not just first one which is why your `c` can't be grater than 1.
2. Strings are immutable so since `replace` can't edit original string, it returns new one with replaced characters which you can store back in `sb` reference.

---

Anyway if you would be able to use other Java resources beside `java.lang.*` or `java.util.Scanner` simple approach would be using `Map` which will map character with number of its occurrences. Very helpful here is `merge` method added in Java 8 allows us to pass `key` `initialValue` `combination of old and new value`

So your code can look like:

```
String sb = ...

Map<Character, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();
for (char ch : sb.toCharArray()) {
    map.merge(ch, 1, Integer::sum);
}
map.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + "\t" + v));
```

Comment: "cannot use any other libraries except java.lang and Scanner to input" Map would be my first option though.

Comment: @JohnE. Thanks. I tried to separate both parts making last one more like bonus which other readers who are not in same situation as OP could use.

Answer (score 0):

This should be a good code to print frequency using user input:

```
public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter numbers "); 
        String time = in.nextLine(); //USER INPUT
        time = time.replace(":", "");
        char digit[] = {time.charAt(0), time.charAt(1), time.charAt(2), time.charAt(3)};
        int[] count = new int[digit.length];
        Arrays.sort(digit);

        for (int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++)
        {
            count[i]++;
            if (i + 1 < digit.length)
            {
                if (digit[i] == digit[i + 1])
                {
                    count[i]++;
                    i++;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < digit.length; i++)
        {
            if (count[i] > 0)
            {
                System.out.println(digit[i] + " appears " + count[i]+" time(s)");
            }
        }
    }
```